# How do I know the parent of my selected object?

Tags: parent

I downloaded a car model and selected the steering wheel. I want to rename it now. Unfortunately, it is attached to some parent objects so I cannot find it in the hierarchy (see at screenshot). Is there a method how I find it without checking every object manually ?

Kind regards

[image: How can i find the parent of my steering wheel in the hierarchy at the right?]

Comment: Change your Outliner display settings to "selected". Then you can rename your object. I'm sure there is a way better and more intelligent method, but this is something you can try in the mean time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read this information in the properties panel, Relations tab.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the parent had another parent so that did not help me. But otherwise, thanks to you I found the way to go! Just copy the name of the selected object and enter it in the search. Then it shows your selected object and all its parents.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I'd long wondered how to find out the parent of an object.

Answer (score 3):

Using the search with the selected object's name is a good way. Thanks for your answers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For finding the object in the tree: Select the object in the scene and then move your cursor over into the Tree. Press numpad "." will take you to it in the tree. This also works in reverse. Select in Tree and move over to scene, then press numpad . to go to that object.